# Two classes issue

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I have asked you about `GregorianCalendar` and `Calendar` and some people said that `Calendar` is better. So I did it with `Calender` class.

I have a problem with one method: `JavaApplication1#whichIsEarlier(),` always receives error. Please check it, if you can. How to resolve it? I'll appreciate your help.

```
 public class JavaApplication1 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar yy =Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar xx= Calendar.getInstance();
    xx.set(2001, 10,10);
    Data dt = new Data(yy);
    Data xt = new Data(xx);
    Data dd = new Data( yy, xx);
    System.out.println(dt.toString());
    System.out.println(xt.toString());       
    System.out.println(dd.whichIsEarlier());
}
}


class Data {
    private Calendar calendar;
     Calendar cale;
    Data(Calendar x){

    calendar = x;
}

Data(Calendar x, Calendar y){
    calendar = x;
    cale = y;
}

public String toString(){ 
    String months[] = {"Jan","Feb", "Mar" , "Apr", "Mai", "June", "July","Aug",
        "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"};
    String str = "";
    str = "Data: "+ calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) +" "+ months[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]+
        " "+ calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return str;

    }

    public String whichIsEarlier(Calendar cale){
        String str = "";
        if(calendar.after(cale)) str = calendar.toString() ;
        else str = cale.toString();
        return str +" jest wczesniej";
    }
 }
```

Comment: First check the signature of the method `whichIsEarlier`, and then see if you are invoking it correctly?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "Some people said that `Calendar` is better" - well `GregorianCalendar` is simply a subclass of `Calendar`. It's not a matter of one being "better" - it's a matter of choosing which to use based on the context.

Comment: @JonSkeet Also, `Calendar` is abstract. It just so happens that `GregorianCalendar` is the only concrete subclass most people have ever seen, but otherwise all the usual interface/implementation issues apply.

Comment: @hexafraction The error is obvious: `whichIsEarlier()` cannot be applied to `whichIsEarlier(Calendar)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And the compiler error message in such cases is quite clear.

Comment: So, it's impossible to do it?Is method wichIsEalier made correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would clean up your code:

```
class Data {
  private Calendar calendar;

  Data(Calendar x) { calendar = x; }

  public String whichIsEarlier(Data other) {
    return (calendar.after(other.calendar)? this : other)
        + " jest wczesniej";
  }
```

(I have elided `toString`; I'm not getting into its issues for this answer).

Note:

- removed the `cale` instance variable
- removed the two-argument constructor;
- `whichIsEarlier` accepts another `Data`, not another `Calendar`;
- its return value doesn't call `calendar.toString` but rather your own object's toString
- and it does it implicitly (string concatenation does that).

And now the main method should go like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Calendar yy =Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar xx= Calendar.getInstance();
  xx.set(2001, 10,10);
  Data dt = new Data(yy);
  Data xt = new Data(xx);
  System.out.println(dt.whichIsEarlier(xt));
}
```

Comment: I know that I can get a punishment for that, but thank you so much i was looking for it for a long time and I have noone who can explain it me. :)!

Comment: No punishment, people here just like to remind newcomers about accepting answers, which you already have :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(dd.whichIsEarlier());
```

is problematic as you only define a `Data#whichIsEarlier(Calender)`.

Please make sure that either the `whichIsEarlier` call passes in a calendar object, or you create a new `whichIsEarlier` that takes no arguments and has calendars predefined.

Comment: ok, so i have to do like that: System.out.println(dt.whichIsEalier(xx));  ?

Comment: @dzoni Yes, so you call `Data#whichIsEarlier(Calendar)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks but next problem which was appeared is calendar.toString() inside whichIsEalier, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @dzoni Then create your own implementation that accepts a `Calendar` and generates a string with its properties.